# Making installer with NetBeans [C++]

Tags: c++, netbeans, installation, exe

I have made a simple program with NetBeans in C++, now that is finished I would like to use it outside the IDE, how should I proceed? I have been looking around but didn't get anything clear. Should I make an installer? (its not such a big program so I dont know if just the exe could work - although I have found none in the project directory)
Thankyou very much in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Especially if you have a small project, NetBeans packing options are very useful.

To create a package:

**`Right click on your Project -> More Build Commands -> Build Package`**

To configure what has to go into your package and what not, you can customize it here:

**`Right click on your Project -> Properties -> Packaging`**

Make sure you have libs, required files etc. selected in **`Packing Files`**, so everything that's required by your application is together.

Note: Per default, a Tar-Archive is used, Zip, RPM, Debian Packages and some more are possible too.